# How to test an unpublished android game that uses google play game services?

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am trying to test google play services features in an app, without publishing the app.
I went through the below link to do that.

https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling

This process worked earlier but i think it has changed now, as i am getting the following error even after checking all the steps mentioned in the link above.

*"The application is incorrectly configured. Check that the package name and signing certificate match the client ID created in Developer Console. Also, if the application is not yet published, check that the account you are trying to sign in with is listed as a tester account. See logs for more information."*

Does anyone know if there has been any change in the process or if i am missing out something? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to publish an app for testing. From the error it seems that the users/testers who want to test are not white listed. Quoting from the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/testpub).

***If your game is in an unpublished state, you must whitelist the user accounts that you want to grant access for testing. Otherwise, your testers will encounter OAuth and 404 errors when attempting to access the Google Play games services endpoints. Also remember to add yourself as a tester, or the Play Games SDK will not work for your user account***

Hope this Helps!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to publish the app before it becomes available for testing.

If you publish the app and it is only in the "alpha testing" section then it is NOT available to general public; it is only available to activated testers in the alpha section.

EDIT: One additional note: "normal" uses will not find your app on Google Play, but also the activated tester can not find the application by using the search box.

Only the direct link to the application package will work (only for the activated testers).

Comment: Has there been a process change? 'Cause i was able to test the applications without publishing earlier. Also the following is mentioned in the testing section  - "The following groups can test your saved drafts for Google Play game services before they are published."